# Installing fitdistrplus into R studio

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install fitdistrplus into R studio version 4.3.2 and it says I need to install "Rtools" first but I don't know what version of Rtools that I need.

install.packages("fitdistrplus")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/julia/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/fitdistrplus_1.1-11.zip'

I tried install.packages("Rtools")

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: From memory you can download Rtools directly based on the version of R you are using: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. It doesn't use the usual `install.packages()` convention.

Comment: That worked for Rtools thank you. I am now getting this error. What fitdistplus would I need.   Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘fitdistrplus’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: I tested and can install and load the package with R Version 4.3.2. You can check which version you have by running `R.Version()`. Beyond that, it's hard to say.